# not show cshtml file in add new item in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, razor, visual-studio-2022

I am using visual studio `2022`.
not show `cshtml file` in add new item in visual studio.
i am add mvc and razor and not show `cshtml file` or `javascript` file in add new item.
[image]

Comment: in Individual components for .NET  Enables .NET Framework project templates, item templates

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Make sure you choose to install the ".NET Framework project and item templates":

[image: Screenshot showing selected optional features in installer, including the aforementioned .NET Framework project and item templates]

Answer (score 1):

Select the ‘Web’ section in the menu sidebar. It (All installed razor controls) should be there if razor is installed.
[image]

Comment: i am install razor and not show

Comment: When I created a Razor project it should be located under “web”. Can you make sure that your project that was created is in fact a razor project, not a C# forms project or something else?

Comment: when open project in vs 2019 Everything is right

Comment: Are you sure you created a razor project? You should see files that end in .razor already created. What does your solution explorer look like?

Comment: i am using mvc project

Comment: Individual components for .NET i am not  Enables .NET Framework project templates, item templates.this is problem me.thank you